# how to rename Databricks job cluster name during runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

I have created an ADF pipeline with Notebook activity. This notebook activity automatically creates databricks job clusters with autogenerated job cluster names.

**1. Rename Job Cluster during runtime from ADF**

I'm trying to rename this job cluster name with the process/other names during runtime from ADF/ADF linked service.

instead of job-59, i want it to be replaced with <process_name>_

[image]

**2. Rename ClusterName Tag**

Wanted to replace Default generated ClusterName Tag to required process name

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: to verify the cost per cluster and to identify the cluster with the process name.

Comment: add custom tags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#jobsclusterspecnewcluster

Answer (score 0):

Settings for the job can be updated using the [Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#jobsjobsserviceresetjob) or [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#jobsjobsserviceupdatejob) endpoints.

Cluster tags allow you to easily monitor the cost of cloud resources used by various groups in your organization. You can specify tags as key-value pairs when you create a cluster, and Azure Databricks applies these tags to cloud resources like VMs and disk volumes, as well as [DBU usage reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/usage-detail-tags-azure).

For detailed information about how pool and cluster tag types work together, see [Monitor usage using cluster, pool, and workspace tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/usage-detail-tags-azure).

For convenience, Azure Databricks applies four default tags to each cluster:  `Vendor`,  `Creator`,  `ClusterName`, and  `ClusterId`.

These tags propagate to detailed  [cost analysis reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/quick-acm-cost-analysis)  that you can access in the Azure portal.

Checkout an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61494276/15969417) how billing works.